# node's are not intersection while using loops inside of an array?

Tags: java, processing

My problem is wherever i click a node appears and for the second click another node appears with connected edge...so i want that When i click at any location, the node should be generated at the closest grid intersection point. I tried using loops. 
and i'm trying to do that without "class"

```java
int n_partition=10;
int length = 101;
PVector[] position = new PVector[length];
int BallNum;

void setup() {
    size(600, 360);
    background(255);
}

void draw() {
    fill(255);
    grid();
    fill(0);
}

void mousePressed(){
    stroke(0);
    BallNum++;
    position[BallNum]= new PVector(mouseX, mouseY);
    circle(position[BallNum].x, position[BallNum].y, 10);
    if (BallNum > 1) {
        line(position[BallNum].x,position[BallNum].y,position[BallNum- 
        1].x,position[BallNum-1].y);
        line(position[1].x,position[1].y,position[BallNum].x,position[BallNum] .y);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < position[BallNum].length; ++ i) {
        position[BallNum]  = position[BallNum].get(i);
        position[BallNum]  = position[BallNum].get((i+1) % position[BallNum].length);
        line(position[BallNum].x, position[BallNum].y, 
        position[BallNum].x, position[BallNum].y);   
    }
}
```

I EXPECT THE NODE SHOULD GO TO THE CLOSEST INTERSECTION.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to calculate the nearest position of the mouse to a point on the grid. For that you've to know the width (`tile_width`) and the height (`tile_height`) of cell. 
The index of the cell can be calculated by the dividing the mouse position to the size of a tile and [`round()`](https://processing.org/reference/round_.html) the result to an integral value (e.g. `round(mouseX / (float)tile_width)`).
Don't draw anything in int the `mousePressed` callback. The only thing you've to do there is to add a pint to the list:

```java
void mousePressed(){
    int tile_width  = width / n_partition;  // adapt this for your needs 
    int tile_height = height / n_partition;

    int x = round(mouseX / (float)tile_width) * tile_width;
    int y = round(mouseY / (float)tile_height) * tile_height;
    position[BallNum]= new PVector(x, y);
    BallNum++;
}
```

All the drawing has to be done in `draw()`. Draw the lines and points in separate loops:

```java
void draw() {
    background(255);
    grid();

    // draw the lines in a loop 
    strokeWeight(3);
    stroke(0, 0, 255);
    for (int i = 0; i < BallNum; ++ i) {
        int i2 = (i+1) % BallNum;
        line(position[i].x, position[i].y, position[i2].x, position[i2].y); 
    }

    // draw balls in a loop
    strokeWeight(1);
    stroke(0, 0, 0);
    fill (255, 0, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < BallNum; ++i) {
        circle(position[i].x, position[i].y, 10);
    }
}
```

Note, the scene is consecutively redrawn in every frame. Before the scene is drawn, the entire window has to be "cleared" by [`background()`](https://processing.org/reference/background_.html).

See the result:

[image]